# Unable to find the file saved in WebContent

Tags: java, file-upload

I'm using Glassfish 3 and Eclipse as my IDE.

In the application, I developed a small file upload feature which saves the files in `WebContent`. I know it is a bad practice because I'm loosing all the files on every redeploy and so on.

The file is saved at:

```
E:\java\server\Glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\myApp\upload\story\79.png
```

Than I try to list render that picture in my `.xhtml` file using:

```
<img src = "upload/story/79.png" />
```

Weirdly enough, on the Servlet side (or ManagedBean in my case) when deciding if the image exists or notit all looks fine and the image is found on the disk. However, in the browser the image is not displayed because it fails to load the given URL.

How can I solve this problem?